# Swift 4 generic array as parameter in generic class

Tags: ios, swift, generics, xctest, swift4

I have a matcher for using in tests

```
class GWMatcher<ResultType> {
    let result: ResultType
    let message: String

    init(result: ResultType, message: String) {
        self.result = result
        self.message = message
    }
}
```

And I want to add extension to use it with arrays. I want it to be smth like this:

```
extension GWMatcher where ResultType == [Equatable] {
    func checkEqual(_ expression: ResultType) {
        XCTAssertEqual(self.result, expression, self.message)
    }
}
```

But compiler says:

> Cannot invoke `XCTAssertEqual` with an argument list of type `([Equatable], Array<Equatable>, String)`.

Does anybody have an idea, is it possible to do such a stuff or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are hitting an edge case of Swift type system. In particular, the generic constraint:

```swift
extension GWMatcher where ResultType == [Equatable]
```

should really be specified as:

```swift
extension GWMatcher where ResultType == [T] where T: Equatable
```

but this last form isn't currently supported (for *extensions*). This matters because a Swift protocol does *not* conform to itself, which would need to be true to `[Equatable]` work as expected (that is why a concrete type `T` is required). I know, tricky as hell... ;)

Also, the standard [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol can only be used as a generic constraint because it has [`Self`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable#topics) requirements (protocols using *associated types* also behave similarly). This Swift limitation may also be to blame here.

**Workaround**. Anyway, as a *less* type-safe workaround, try this instead:

```swift
extension GWMatcher {
    func checkEqual<T: Equatable>(_ expression: [T]) {
        guard let result = self.result as? [T] else {
            XCTFail("Expected type \([T].self)")
            return
        }
        XCTAssertEqual(result, expression)
    }
}
```

This isn't as type-safe as your original design because it will be available on *all* `GWMatcher` types, including those whose `ResultType` aren't typed as `[Equatable]`. Nevertheless, it should work as expected.